# Add onclick event to nodes in Sigma.js

Tags: javascript, graph, click

I have a very simple example in sigma.js that reads a gexf-file with some additional data.

```
// Instanciate sigma.js and customize rendering :
var sigInst = sigma.init(document.getElementById('graph-container')).drawingProperties({
    defaultLabelColor: '#fff',
    defaultLabelSize: 14,
    defaultLabelBGColor: '#fff',
    defaultLabelHoverColor: '#000',
    labelThreshold: 6,
    defaultEdgeType: 'straight'
}).graphProperties({
    minNodeSize: 0.5,
    maxNodeSize: 5,
    minEdgeSize: 1,
    maxEdgeSize: 1
}).mouseProperties({
    maxRatio: 4
});

// Parse a GEXF encoded file to fill the graph
// (requires "sigma.parseGexf.js" to be included)
sigInst.parseGexf(gexfFile);
```

This is actually just taken from a tutorial. Now I'd like to add an on-click event to all nodes. Can anyone tell me a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step1 - Writing the event handler**

```
function onClick(event) {
    window.console.log("clicked!");
}
```

**Step 2 - Finding the event name**

I've been wondering for a while what the event name could be. It appears the "onmouseover", "onmousedown", etc have been renamed with the "onmouse" part truncated and "nodes" appended at the end.

So for a click event it will be 'downnodes'

**Step 3 - Linking the handler to the click event:**

You have to use the bind() function to bind an event handler to an event name.

```
sigInst.bind('downnodes',onClick).draw();
```

**Events list @ v1.0.3**

Thanks to Matt for providing the list.

click, rightClick, clickStage, doubleClickStage, rightClickStage, clickNode, clickNodes, doubleClickNode, doubleClickNodes, rightClickNode, rightClickNodes, overNode, overNodes, outNode, outNodes, downNode, downNodes, upNode, upNodes - all should be lowercase.

Comment: Thanks. How did you find the event names?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I looked at the source on github.

Comment: List of all the events @ v1.0.3: click, rightClick, clickStage, doubleClickStage, rightClickStage, clickNode, clickNodes, doubleClickNode, doubleClickNodes, rightClickNode, rightClickNodes, overNode, overNodes, outNode, outNodes, downNode, downNodes, upNode, upNodes

Comment: **Events may just be lowercase only.

Comment: Thanks for the list. I added it in the answer.

Comment: In fact, events do not seem to be lowercased, sigmaInstance.bind('clicknode') does not work, instead of sigmaInstance.bind('clickNode'), which work.
Are you sure about this event list ?

I cannot figure why but downNode and upNode does not seem to work in 1.0.3 version :

http://jsfiddle.net/5w2t8azz/

Answer (score 12):

According to the official documentation:

```
s = new sigma({...});

// Bind the events:
s.bind('overNode outNode clickNode doubleClickNode rightClickNode', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.data.node.label, e.data.captor);
});
```

https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/events.html

(The accepted answer did not work for me.)

Comment: This is the right answer in my opinion too. It should be noted that `overNode outNode clickNode doubleClickNode rightClickNode` are all seperate events and can be bound with a separate callback if needed.